# jQuery UI Autocomplete not working when returned JSON data has line breaks in it

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

MY AIM

Use jQuery UI Autocomplete to search for a book and when a book is clicked from the suggestion dropdown, populate the remainder of the HTML form with details of the book selected by using the `select` function of the autocomplete.

THE PROBLEM

As long as the returned data does not contain a line break (I have a table field called `description` in the database and it has line breaks in the stored data ) the autocomplete works like a charm. But if I include the `description` field data into the returned array, the suggestion dropdown fails to show up. However when checked with Firebug, data is being returned; just not showing up

THE CODE

```
// STORING INFORMATION FROM THE DATABASE
$items[$r['book_id']] = array('name'=>$r['book_name'],
                              'category'=>$r['c_id'],
                              'author'=>$r['book_author'],
                              'vendor'=>$r['book_publisher'],
                              'edition'=>$r['book_edition'],
            Culprit here -->  'description'=>$r['book_description'],
                              'price'=>$r['book_price'],
                              'date'=>$r['date']);



 // DATA FOR POPULATING THE HTML FORM (USING ui.item.<index name>)
   $result = array();
   foreach ($items as $key=>$value)
   {
      array_push($result, array("id"=>$key,
                                "label"=>$key."-".$value['name'],
                                "value" => strip_tags($value['name']),
                                "name" => $value['name'],
                                "cat" => $value['category'],
                                "author" => $value['author'],
                                "vendor" => $value['vendor'],
                                "edition" => $value['edition'],
                                "description" => $value['description'],
                                "price" => $value['price'],
                                "date" => $value['date']));
    }
    // $result is then supplied to a function which converts the data to json
```

If I remove the `description` entry from the `$items` and `$result` arrays, everything works as expected. I tried a couple of things after going through SO threads here:

WHAT I TRIED

Tried `str_replace('\n', '\\n', $r['book_description'])`

Tried `str_replace('<br />', '\\n', $r['book_description'])`

Out of frustration even tried `urlencode($r['book_description'])`

But none of them seemed to work. Is there a workaround for this one?

Thanks in advance.

---

**UPDATE**

Using `json_encode` on the returned set is resulting into:

[image]

Comment: What spits out this JSON, PHP?

Comment: You mean you want the returned data?

Comment: It's late, I'm an idiot. Obviously it's PHP. you just need to json_encode your array before spitting it back. It'll handle linebreaks, that's what it's for my ninja.

Comment: Using json_encode splits a record into individual characters. Hold on, I will post a screenshot

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Screenshot attached

Comment: @Ohgodwhy `json_encode` worked. Instead of using it on the returned array, I used it on `$r['book_description']`. Could you post your suggestion as an answer so that I can accept it as a answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)? ..It should escape everything for you. You could also try something like

```
$newDesc = str_replace(PHP_EOL, "", $r['book_description']);
```

or

```
$newDesc = str_replace(chr(10), "", $r['book_description']);
$newDesc = str_replace(chr(13), "", $newDesc);
```

Comment: Shall I use those str_replace and the apply json_encode too? Or just try str_replace without json_encode?

Comment: Only use `json_encode`. theses two lines can instead fix you line break problem.

Comment: @vittore Yep, that worked. I was using it at the wrong place which caused the wierd display as shown in the screenshot

Answer (score 2):

Escape sequences (\n \r \t etc...) only works with double quotes.
Replace:

```
      str_replace('\n', '\\n', $r['book_description'])
```

For this one:

```
      str_replace("\n", "\\n", $r['book_description'])
```

and then works

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I already got what I was looking for